# Must have SSL Cert Providers?

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate

I am looking into getting an SSL certificate and was wondering what the best providers are? Please base your answer on price and supported browsers.

I am shopping around for the best deal, but also would like a robust SSL cert that just about any browser will not have issues with.

(Just as a side note, what to people generally think about the SSL Cert provider DigiCert?)

Comment: I changed this to be a little less broad.  You should make this a community wiki.

Comment: Do you need to support Windows Mobile devices? By default, Windows Mobile only supports certain certificate authorities. If your CA isn’t on the list, you will need to install certificates on each device. Here is the list (PDF - look on page 12) http://download.microsoft.com/download/c/b/d/cbdc18d1-1a01-4736-a557-08474ec73443/Mobile_Certificates_White_Paper.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We've used Digicert for a couple of years and have been happy with their support folks.  They do use a chained cert which has caused some problems for mobile browsers (the iPhone works well but not Blackberry).  We've never heard complaints from desktop users.

The instructions on their site are clear and easy to use and their pricing is competitive.  I believe they have a 30 day trial so that would probably be your best way to experiment with them.

Answer (score 8):

I think you can look at [this related question](https://serverfault.com/questions/62999/choosing-the-right-ssl-certifcate)

For cheapness I suggest the one pointed out in one comment ([namecheap.com](http://namecheap.com)), about 10$/yr and quite good support on every modern browser. No cert chains involved.

EDIT:

we are also using since 4 year rapidSSL for a GEOTrust wildcard certificate, never had an issue with any OS or browser with this CA.

Answer (score 5):

If the site will be visted by people that are not on machines controlled by you (i.e. ones you can install the needed SSL certs to yourself), I would only recommend [Thawte](http://www.thawte.com/).  I have yet to find a device their authority is not supported on.

Per Nate's comment, Windows Mobile is the biggest group of devices that caused me headaches in the past.  Palm Treo's are also problematic, with many of the cheaper cert authorities.

Answer (score 2):

godaddy is very good, cheap and very fast i just purchased 10 year SSL cert for my primary domain

Answer (score 2):

We use rapidSSL

Comment: Beware. We tried their certificates and found that Windows Mobile did not recognize them by default. You have to install the certificate on each device. We switched to certificatesforexchange.com.

Comment: A person I know had a few issues with rapidSSL working in certain browsers, though this may not be true for current up to date browsers.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest Network Solutions, and disagree with Go-Daddy, the support when I dealt with them was horrible. You get what you pay for.

Answer (score 2):

If you definitely, absolutely, HAVE to have it be guaranteed to work on all browsers, all systems, everything, you're going to want to go with a certificate from [VeriSign](http://www.verisign.com/ssl/).  They're one of the oldest SSL certificate vendors, and while they are expensive to get, finding a machine that doesn't have the root certificate installed for them is like finding a needle in a haystack.

Answer (score 2):

Try [www.sslshopper.com](http://www.sslshopper.com) for a side-by-side comparison of certificates from different providers.

Answer (score 1):

Try Comodo.  We've been using it for years as a Reseller.  It's reasonable, but not the cheapest.  No problems so far.